# Is there a way to create a bubble chart in c3.js using 3 variables (x,y,z)?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I'm building on this [project](http://jsfiddle.net/3jfe75r8/). Where there are 2 data sets. In this example, there is only x and y data, but what if there was a 3d dimension? How would I enter it to adjust the size of the bubbles?

I know I can use a function to adjust the bubble size, but could I do some type of lookup? to search for the relevant z value to use as bubble size?

```
point: {
r: function(d) { 
   return d.value * 5;
}
```

},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define Z-values in separate object:

```
var Z = {
    "id1": [0.2, ... , 0.2], // whatever values you want
    "id2": [1.4, ..., 1.3]
}
```

Then in point function you can take id and index of current dot. So you can get z-value:

```
point: {
    r: function(d) {
        return Z[d.id][d.index]
    }
},
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/3jfe75r8/98/)